# Swift countElements() with an array

Tags: generics, casting, swift

## Question

Is it possible to invoke `countElements()` with an `Array` in my setup?

---

### Problem in detail

The `countElements()` works fine with `String`. However I cannot figure out how to cast `thing` to an `Array` and thus not invoking `countElements()`.

Please note that the method signature must be `func myCount(thing: Any?) -> Int`, since this is to be [used in my open source project](https://github.com/neoneye/SpecificationPattern/blob/master/Classes/CountSpecification.swift#L30).

```
func myCount(thing: Any?) -> Int {
    if thing == nil {
        return -1
    }
    if let x = thing as? String {
        return countElements(x)
    }
    if let y = thing as? Array<Any> {
        return countElements(y)    // this if is never taken
    }
    return -1
}

myCount(nil)        // -1
myCount("hello")    // 5
myCount([1, 2, 3])  // BOOM, returns -1, I'm expecting 3 returned
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me. It feels a bit hacky though casting back and forth.

```
func myCount(thing: Any?) -> Int {
    if thing == nil {
        return -1
    }
    if let x = thing as? String {
        return countElements(x)
    }
    if let y = thing as? NSArray {
        return countElements(y as Array)
    }
    return -1
}
```

Comment: You could also `return y.count` instead of casting it back to `Array`.

Comment: That's a good point. I was just focused on getting countElements to work

Comment: I would make it return an optional, so that instead of returning -1 at the end, it would be nil.

Comment: Could you please explain why by casting it back and forth from `NSArray` to `Array` makes it work? Thanks.